# Excel 365 ProPlus - VBA - Point Object - Methods Set Property & Get Property

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to use? Is it possible to set transparency via these methods? Do you have a link to documentation? Official docs do not mention these methods:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.point%28object%29

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim chart As chart
    Dim seriesCol As SeriesCollection
    Dim series As series
    Dim points As points
    Dim point As point
    Dim x As Object

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects(1)
    Set chart = chartObj.chart
    Set seriesCol = chart.SeriesCollection
    Set series = seriesCol.Item(1)
    Set points = series.points
    Set point = points.Item(1)

    point.SetProperty "Transparency", 0.5
    Set x = point.GetProperty("Format")
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Excel 2016, `point.SetProperty` and `point.GetProperty` raises a 438 error "Object does not support this property or method.

Comment: @DavidZemens I am running excel 2016 too, these methods pop up in intelisense and can be found in object browser

Comment: Not here they don't. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ even when I toggle "View Hidden Members".

Comment: Can you screenshot that from Object Browser? Maybe there is some additional hint or information that might be gained from seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: @DavidZemens guessing OP is running an Office 365 build and not Excel 2016 perpetual license; 365 has more features.

Comment: yes 366 ProPlus - so Microsoft is developing vba?! :-p

Comment: The Excel object model isn't VBA *the language*, it's just a COM type library - and yes, the current stance is that Microsoft will keep adding to the Excel type library for VBA code to consume and be able to programmatically access the new features as they ship =)  ...but VBA itself isn't getting any updates that I know of

Comment: the COM type library can be used by any language such as javascript. developing language would be adding try catch throw stuff etc OK think I see thank you

Comment: `.GetProperty` and `.SetProperty` have been around for a long time, so it's not Excel 2016 vs Office 365 vs whatever. I have been trying to figure out how to use these for years, and whatever I try fails. There is no real documentation for them, even though they appear in the Object Browser. It's a mystery.